# UIActivityViewController won't show any options to share

Tags: ios, swift3, uiactivityviewcontroller, uitableviewrowaction

I am trying to share something from tableViewCell but whenever I press on share, it displays the activityViewController but wont give me any options to share it with. I tried running it on my iPhone as well and same issue appears.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let shareActions = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Share") { (_ rowAction: UITableViewRowAction, _ indexPath: IndexPath) in

        let sharingItem = self.eventsArray[indexPath.row]

        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [sharingItem], applicationActivities: nil)

        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

Picture - [This is what happens when I try to share it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsVnl.png)

Again, i tried running it on my phone and same thing happens. when i click on more, it doesn't show any applications options there either. Any idea what's wrong here? Thank you in advance!

Comment: r u testing on simulator

Comment: @BhupatBheda I tested on both, simulator AND my phone

Comment: @KunjPatel put break point in this method and in console print `activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes`.

Comment: @dahiya_boy i don't have such method in my code above. I am sorry if I'm not understanding you

Comment: This is not a method, it gives you the array of types that are excluded to show in activityViewController.

Comment: which kind of data you have shared in sharingItem .

Comment: Have you added a sharing extension target?